# Mysql + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

```
 INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;
```

Is it possible to set this so it doesn't require and entire matching row.
eg: if column 'a' is a duplicate then do the update?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ON DUPLICATE KEY does just that... if the data you're inserting violates a unique key requirement, turn it into an update on the row which has the key combination which caused the violation. If your primary key is only one of the fields (e.g. 'a'), and you already had a row in the table where a=1, then you'd get an update instead and that original row would get its 'c' set to 3.

If it's a composite key (say, 'a,b'), then if you had an existing records with a=1 and b=2, then that rows' C would get changed to 3 instead of a new record being created.

If there's no unique/primary keys on this table, then you'd never get an update, it'd just be an extra-verbose insert statement.

Comment: thanks heaps - understand and have updated/changed how the unique key is setup - works great... will tick when the time limit passes...

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not a row is a duplicate is dictated by the constraints on the table. This would be your primary key, as well as all unique keys on the table. So, if you have a non multi column unique index on the `a` column, then it would work.

Otherwise, you could probably accomplish that with a trigger.